# How to post array of dictionary with alamofire in swift?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have to post array of dictionary value like this.

```
{
    "reservedHour": "2019-11-01T14:55+0900",
    "reservedBoxSize": "sm",
    "products": [{
        "id": 312
    }],
    "boxArea": {
        "id": 66
    },
    "type": "RENT"
}
```

`products` is Array of Json Object.

So I try this.

```swift
func requestReserveAvailableDate(type: String, reserveHour: String, boxAreaID: Int, boxSize: String, productIDs: [Int], completionHandler: @escaping (_ availableDates: [String]?, _ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
let parameters: [String: Any] = ["type": type,
                                 "reservedHour": reserveHour,
                                 "boxArea": ["id": boxAreaID],
                                 "reservedBoxSize": boxSize,
                                 "products": productIDs.map({ ["id": $0] })]
...
```

But this is not working.
I am using alamofire only for all API calls. Please help me how I can solve it.

Comment: How are you passing the variables into the function?

Comment: @HarryJ Just array of int([Int]). you can see that my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try like this

```
var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
parameters = ["type": type,
              "reservedHour": reserveHour,
              "reservedBoxSize": boxSize,
              "boxArea": [],
              "products": []]

var boxAreaParams:[String:Any] = [:]
boxAreaParams = ["id": boxAreaID]
parameters["boxArea"] = boxAreaParams

var productsParmas: [string: Any] = [:]
productParams = ["id": productId]

var product = parameter["products"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]()
product.append(productParams)
parameters["product"] = product
```